# Is an abstract class contains at least one unimplemented method?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Does an abstract class contain at least one unimplemented method? Could some explain please?

Comment: Generally speaking, "no".  You can have implementations in an abstract class.  This depends though on the language you're talking about.  Could you clarify/add the language tag?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an abstract class is simply a class that is declared to be abstract:

```
abstract class ThisInAnAbstractClass { }
```

You cannot create instances of an abstract class.  An abstract class is allowed, but not required, to have abstract methods.

Answer (score 1):

If your class has at least one abstract method, the class should be mentioned as "abstract"; not the other way around.

Your class can be abstract with concrete methods!